# Linux make can't link against Boost non-header only libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I successfully switched to Linux, and I really start to love it. Except that I can't link code against Boost libraries that are non-header only.

Steps that I have taken:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install libboost.*-dev` in terminal to install the Boost libraries
2. Let CMake generate my make-files and locate the Boost libraries as I have done it on Windows.
3. Run `make` to compile.

The same code compiles and link fine under Windows with Microsoft Visual C++.

#### Further information

- [Console Output](http://paste2.org/p/1572495)
- [Source](https://github.com/Mythli/RCMeta)

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Both links are broken (404). Can you remedy it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output and your CMakeFiles it doesn't look like you are linking your code to the Boost filesystem library.

That is,

```
target_link_libraries(RCMeta ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY})
```

Note: I may have the variable name wrong for that library you may have to double check it.

You can also use the generic `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` variable,

```
target_link_libraries(RCMeta ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

for your RCMeta library.

Comment: Do I understand you correct that I have to link RCMeta (the static library) against boost not the executable?

Comment: @Mythli: I don't think it's possible to compile / link the library otherwise.

Comment: Worked almost like you said. &Learned something new. Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by *"CMakeFiles"*? Do you mean *"CMake files"*? Or *"CMakeLists.txt"*? Or something else?